# ORDER/SORT Column mixed number and number prefixed by char

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a varchar column conteining a code, this code could by only numbers, or number prefixed by a char for example i have a column containing this data :

```
+------+
| Code |
+------+
|  1   |
|  C1  |
|  2   |
|  3   |
|  C3  |
|  F3  |
|  F1  |
|  F17 |
|  C9  |
|  C10 |
|  C47 |
| C100 |
| C134 |
| A234 |
|C1245 |
|   10 |
|  100 |
+------+
```

And so on ...

I want to sort this column by this rules :

1. Only numeric code
2. Prefixed code with the letter part order alfanumerically and numeric part ordered as a number

I want to achieve a resultset ordered like this :

```
+------+
| Code |
+------+
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
| 10   |
| 100  |
| A234 |
|  C1  |
|  C3  |
|  C9  |
|  C10 |
|  C47 |
| C100 |
| C134 |
|C1245 |
|  F1  |
|  F3  |
|  F17 |
+------+
```

How can i get a resultset ordered with this criteria ? 
I've tried with a query like this :

```
SELECT Code FROM Code_List ORDER BY case when Code like '%[a-z]%' then 99999999999999999999999999999999 else convert(decimal, Code) end
```

But i get a result that order first the number and then the prefixed number but the alpha prefixed number is ordered like char and not in the manner i want it...

The only numeric record should be ordered following the rules of the numeric order and no the character order so if the only numeric record are :

```
+------+
| Code |
+------+
|  1   |
|  47  |
|  2   |
|  3   |
|  6   |
|  100 |
|  112 |
|  10  |
```

I want to get :

```
+------+
| Code |
+------+
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
|  6   |
|  10  |
|  47  |
|  100 |
|  112 |
```

The Database is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Can you have more than one letter on your code?, is it always on the first char?

Comment: I can also have more than one letter as a prefix, but the letter could be only in the prefix, so i can have one char as prefix or two char as prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's no spaces before the values and there can only be 1-char prefix:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN LEFT(Code, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN ' ' ELSE LEFT(Code, 1) END,
  CAST(STUFF(Code, 1, CASE WHEN LEFT(Code, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, '') AS int)
```

Alternatively, the second criterion could be rewritten like this:

```
  CAST(STUFF(Code, 1, PATINDEX('[^0-9]%', Code), '') AS int)
```

`PATINDEX('[^0-9]%', Code)` returns 1 if it finds a non-numeric character at the beginning of `Code`, and 0 otherwise. As a result, `STUFF` either removes 1 character, or none, i.e. same as previously.

Answer (score 4):

```
 CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col) = 1 THEN '@'
    Else LEFT(Col, 1)
 END
,CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col) = 1 THEN Convert(int, Col)
    Else Convert(int, RIGHT(Col, LEN(Col) - 1))
 END
```

Comment: You might want to do `WHEN IsNumeric(Col + '.0e0')` just case the rules change and a number is allowed to prefix a character.

Comment: The prefixed number are ordered correctly but the only number NO . if i have a 10 and a 100 a get : 1,10,100,3,4 , the only number are ordered with the char rules i want it ordered by numeric rules then the result should be : 1,3,4,10,100 .

Comment: @amit_g : I've tried with the Convert(int,Col) and with CAST(Col AS INT) but the result is always ordered as char and no as numeric ... Don't Work ..

Comment: @aleroot - My solution handles this scenario correctly, and I updated it with this test case you mention here (see my answer below).

Comment: @dcp : I've tried but don't work correctly, i get the 47 after the 100 and 112, the order of the numeric part is not numeric order..

Comment: @aleroot, sorry posted the select clause instead of order by from the test code. Updated again. Works fine with test data.

Answer (score 0):

you might try

```
...ORDER by ('A'+Code)
```

Comment: This is assuming there aren't any blanks before the numbers...if so, you might want to trim the 'Code' value...

Comment: That doesn't follow the second rule the op wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Code FROM Code_List ORDER BY Code, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Code,1,1)) = 1 THEN CODE ELSE SUBSTRING(Code,2,LEN(Code)-1) END
```

Obviously assuming that only the first digit can be alpha